# Intermittent Internet on Windows Only

Tags: networking, router

I have just installed a Nighthawk R7000 router inside my home network. I have set it up behind my ISP-provided router/modem and connected my PCs to the R7000 instead of the modem.

The modem's network is 192.168.0.x and the R7000's is 10.0.0.x. R7000 is acting as DHCP with DNS pointing to my Pi-Hole. IPv6 is disabled on the R7000. Dynamic QoS is enabled. I do not think there are any other details of significance to mention although I can always provide if necessary.

I have 2 Linux desktops, one running Arch and one with Linux Mint. I have flawless internet connection on both of them. On the other hand, my brother has a Windows 10 desktop which has intermittent internet connection. This means that every minute or so, the internet connection stops. The internet settings will show "connected but no internet" with the globe symbol displayed instead of the PC and ethernet cable icon. This has worked

This problem happens only on the Windows computer, which makes me suspect some level of incompatibility between the R7000 settings and Win10.

I have:

- Tested on both wired and wireless connections. Both have the same fault.
- Tested with and without the PiHole as DNS. PiHole has no effect on the problem.
- Tested R7000 firmware versions both 1.0.9.32 and the latest available one. Both have the problem.
- Tested with a second Windows device. Problem persists.
- Tried different ethernet cables.
- Tried disabling Windows Firewall, no difference.
- Tried connecting the problematic PC to my router directly, bypassing the switch. Note I can use the switch from Linux with no problems.

If anyone has suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Upgrade the firmware on your Router and see if that helps.

Comment: @John I did try that. Tried both 1.0.9.32 which is deemed a stable firmware for the R7000 and also tried the latest version. Both have the same issue.

Comment: I will look around. I am using Windows on all host machines but not a Nighthawk router and connections are very stable. I am fairly sure it is not a Windows issue.

Comment: @John Thank you. It's probably not something caused by Windoes itself because that's a pretty major flaw. Might be some compatibility issues. I was just remarking that only Win10 devices are having issues

Comment: What is your network adapter on Windows and are you using the latest driver version?

Comment: @harrymc I'll check later but I doubt it's that since the problem happens on two Win10 devices and this problem never occurred on the modem's network. I'll try to update them in a bit though.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I found the solution!

My R7000's network was 10.0.0.X. My modem's is 192.168.100.X.
I realised this when I reset the R7000 while doing some more tests. When the R7000 was set to 192.168.1.X the Windows 10 devices started working flawlessly.

I cannot think of any reasoning as to why this incompatibility arose, and why it affected only Windows devices.

Regardless, my problem can be fixed by changing the subnet to 192.168.X.Y but be careful it is not the same as the one from your modem!